# innodb files in wrong directory

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have created a database called TEST with innodb tables.  When I look in the /var/lib/mysql/TEST directory I see a .frm file for each table.  However, there are no .ibd files in that directory.  The only ibd file I can find is /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1

Should there be at least one ibd file in the /var/lib/mysql/TEST directory?  Why is the ibdata1 file not in /TEST ?

Answer (score 0):

default behavior is all in one, if you looking to separate it you need to read following:

[MySQL :: MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual :: 14.5.2 InnoDB File-Per-Table Mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html)

Comment: My primary issue is why is the file not in the TEST subdirectory?  (I realize that settings creates one file per table)

Comment: That is the way InnoDB works. All tables on all databases are in the `ibdataX` -files in `/var/lib/mysql` by default.